# how to rename HDD, not partitions

Tags: partitioning

How can I change name of my hard drive? I already did it, but i haven't a faintest idea how...

Before:

```
/media/some_numbers_and_chars/my_partitions_with_changed_labels
```

After something that I done:

```
/media/ubuntu/my_partitions_with_changed_labels
```

Screanshoot:
[look at gparted window](https://s13.postimg.org/53jlim5dj/Screenshot_from_2016_11_28_18_13_12.png)

Comment: `/media/ubuntu/my_partitions_with_changed_labels` is a mount point. Do you want to change mount point of your HDD?

Comment: i was thinking about that "ubuntu"part in mount point path. I called it HDD name, because it is parent directory for partitions of my /dev/sdc driver

Comment: Please clarify your question. I can't understand what you want?